# How to limit listview items on first look

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have listview with multiple item. I want to implement one functionality that is initially only 2 items will be displayed and if I press expand button then rest of the items will be displayed. Suggest me how can I implement the same.

Comment: Adapter has `getCount()` method. Just make it to return 2 first, and then, when you *expand*, return full length

Comment: set the condition on the position of the list paste the code of your activity.

Comment: I have list in one adapter and expand button on another adapter. I am not able to understand how can I implement this

Comment: that depends on your code. Only you know it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a boolean value as `isExpand=false;`
when user click on show more make it true and your getCount() code will be something like this

`if(isExpand){
      return 2;
}
return list.size();`